How can I center the hint text in a DropdownButtonFormField
I am using a DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter, and I’d like the hint text to be centered within the dropdown field. Currently, the hint text aligns to the bottom, which doesn’t fit with the rest of my UI design.

Here is my code:
import 'package:clearcommish/utils/constant/app_style.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final String hintText;
  final List<String> items;
  final String? selectedItem;
  final ValueChanged<String?> onChanged;

  const CustomDropdown({
    super.key,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.selectedItem,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: AppStyle.padding(context, vertical: 10),
          child: Text(
            labelText,
            style: AppStyle.darkSlateGrayGilroy(fontSize: AppStyle.fontSize14),
          ),
        ),
        DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          value: selectedItem,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle:
                AppStyle.lightSilverGilroy(fontSize: AppStyle.fontSize14),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppStyle.lightSilver),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppStyle.lightSilver),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppStyle.lightSilver),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppStyle.lightSilver),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
          style: AppStyle.darkSlateGrayGilroy(fontSize: AppStyle.fontSize14),
          dropdownColor: Colors.white,
          items: items.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: onChanged,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Thank you in advance for any guidance!
I’ve tried adjusting the contentPadding and setting alignLabelWithHint: true within InputDecoration, but these haven’t centered the hint text as I expected. Is there a way to center the hint text in a DropdownButtonFormField, or are there any workarounds to achieve this effect?

Try to Center widget inside the DropdownMenuItem like Center(child: Text(value)),  set the isExpanded: true and wrap the hint property in a Center widget.

try the following:

Remove the hint TextStyle.
Add this

 hintText: null,
    hint: Center(
      child: Text(
        hintText,
        style: AppStyle.lightSilverGilroy(fontSize: AppStyle.fontSize14),
      ),
    ),


If this doesn't work properly, you can wrap center widget with padding and give it from left side.


You could try the isDense: false property of DropdownButtonFormField.

When I try to launch your CustomDropdown in a new project I delete all AppStyle styles because I dont have it and the dropdown appear vertically centered. I think you Appstyles causes this alignment issue.

You can set isDense and isExpanded to true and wrap the hint widget with Align to center it:
isDense: true,
isExpanded: true,
hint: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: yourHintWidget,
),

This will center the hint widget within the dropdown.
